# Returning last dataset of sql query execution

Tags: python

I'm working on data saving from sql queries.

My code works good, but it returns only first resulting dataset of query.

For example, if I have following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
GO

SELECT * from Table2
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

I need to return only data from Table2.

DB: Microsoft SQL Server 2017

```
datasets = []

with open('protected_script.sql', 'r') as protected_script:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(protected_script.read())
    datasets.append(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: `datasets.append` should probably by `datasets.extend` since you don't want to just append 1 result but a list of results

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but doesnt `fetchall()` returns a list already?